# Ruby on Rails javascript getting truncated

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this snippet of javascript in a view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function save_RefMD(apt_id,refmd_id) {
        //get the value of the text box
        cb = document.getElementById("selectall"); 
        if(cb == null){
            document.location.href ='/apts/save_refmd?id='+apt_id+'&refmd_id='+refmd_id;
        } else { 
            document.location.href ='/apts/save_refmd?id='+apt_id+'&refmd_id='+refmd_id+'&all='+cb.checked;
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I run a local rails server and look at the page source of that view. It's exactly the same. But when I view the source after it's been deployed to a webserver it looks like this

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
    function save_RefMD(apt_id,refmd_id) {
      //get the value of the text box
      cb = document.getElementById("selectall"); 
      document.location.href ='/apts/save_refmd?id='+apt_id+'&refmd_id='+refmd_id+'&all='+cb.checked;
    }
  </script>
```

Completely strips out my if...else. Anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Are you sure it's "stripping" and not just using an outdated version?

Comment: :(  i think i ran straight for a more complicated reason...

Comment: So that was the answer? It was just an outdated version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was just old code that got deployed. Someone else is in charge of deployment and I was told my stuff made it out there. Assumptions, assumptions. Sorry for the bother.